# EC2 Rstudio Package Install

Tags: r, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install the R package Rcurl on EC2

```
> install.packages("RCurl")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/mike/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RCurl_1.95-4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 870915 bytes (850 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 850 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/mike/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpt1JmNj/downloaded_packages’
```

The download unexpectedly failed for some reason, is there a fix? Am I doing something wrong? I am doing all this on the Rstudio UI on EC2.

Thanks

Comment: You have to install curl first. It is looking for `curl-config`, not finding it, and then stopping.

Comment: I tried to install that via: `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` but afterwards, it still doesn't work..

Comment: If you type `curl-config` does it return the help?

Comment: i tried to install that via *sudo yum install curl-devel*

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `libcurl-dev` to have curl-config.After installing, try typing `curl-config` in command line and see if it shows any help.